# Displaying array data within table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display some data within a table.
In terms of the data I am passing my view, it looks like the following

```
[6] => Array
(
    [leadData] => Array
        (
            [LeadID] => 12345
            [Client] => Test Client
            [Category] => Lead
        )

    [quoteDataIssued] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 2500.00
                    [AmountTax] => 500.00
                    [AmountIncludingTax] => 3000.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 1500.00
                    [AmountTax] => 300.00
                    [AmountIncludingTax] => 1800.00
                )

        )

    [quoteDataDraft] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => 0.00
                    [AmountTax] => 0.00
                    [AmountIncludingTax] => 0.00
                )

        )

)
```

The code I am currently using to display this data is like so

```
@foreach($forecastArray as $array)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $array['leadData']['LeadID'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['leadData']['Category'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['leadData']['Client'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['QuoteID'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['Amount'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['AmountTax'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['AmountIncludingTax'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['EstimatedCost'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['EstimatedCostTax'] or '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $array['quoteDataIssued']['EstimatedCostIncludingTax'] or '' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Now the problem with the above code is that it can only handle one quote.  In the data example I have shown, you can see that
this one has 2 quotes and 1 draft quote.  If there are more than one quote (or a draft quote), then the additional quotes should display on the next tr.

So the above should produce something like this

```
Lead ID   |  Client      |   Category  |   Amount  |   Tax   |  Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345     |  Test Client |  Lead       |   2500    |   500   |  3000
                                           1500    |   300   |  1800
                                           0       |   0     |  0
```

Is there any way this can be achieved?  I was thinking about a foreach within the tr to loop the number of quoteDataIssued, but would this require an inner table? (cant do a nested tr)

Thanks

Comment: You have more than one array element with the same key `quoteDataIssued`?

Comment: @kate-hudson: Do you wnat the constant data to be repeated (copied over)? Like so: `Lead ID | Category | Client Name | Quote ID | Amount  | Amount Tax | Amount inc Tax | Cost | Cost Tax | Cost inc Tax
1266283 | Lead     | Test Client | Q12459   | 1500.00 |     300.00 |        1800.00 | 0.00 |     0.00 |         0.00
1266283 | Lead     | Test Client | Q12458   |    0.00 |       0.00 |           0.00 | 0.00 |     0.00 |         0.00` (should be easier to format in question block ;-)

Comment: @Rifki is right. How can you have two items in the array with the same key? Something is not right in your question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to show that they have a number key as well.

Comment: @kate_hudson please edit your question with correct array data.

Comment: No problem.  I have updated the array of data and shown an example of what I am trying to achieve.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `foreach` loop will do the trick. 
In your code, the displayed `<tr>` it's actually the array in index `6`.